# VxWorks Interpreter - Creating structs

Tags: c, struct, interpreter, vxworks

I'm new to development in VxWorks (using 6.8) and I've run into a situation where I need to pass the address of a struct to a function. Is it possible to create a struct from the interpreter shell? I have a hard copy of a VxWorks programmers guide that is based on v5.5 and it explicitly says that structs cannot be formed/created from the interpreter shell. Has this changed in later versions of VxWorks and if so, how would I make a struct from the command line.

As a VxWorks newb, I was hoping to run the command

```
myStruct = {msg1 ="hi", msg2 = "hello" }
```

and then use the struct in another statement like

```
printf("%s\n", myStruct.msg1)
```

If a struct cannot be created in the interpreter like above, what options can I pursue in order to get the printf statement to print "hi" or "hello" by accessing a member within the struct?

Answer (score 3):

No, as of 6.9 the vxWorks C shell does not support structs.  See the *C Interpreter Limitations* section of the *Wind River Workbench Host Shell User's Guide*.  The shell uses a symbol table that does not track the types of its symbols, and you cannot define types on the command line.

To get the same behavior, you could allocate memory for a struct and then fill it in by address.  The size you allocate doesn't have to be exact, but your memory offsets do.  Your example is easy because you have only 2 pointers, and your struct wouldn't have any padding.  If you are on a 32-bit processor, then the size of a pointer is 4 bytes.  So the first pointer is at offset 0, 1, 2, and 3, and then the 2nd pointer starts at offset 4.

E.g.,

```
-> mystruct = malloc(50);
New symbol "mystruct" added to kernel symbol table.
mystruct = 0x3a320a0: value = 63949520 = 0x3cfcad0
-> mystruct[0] = "hi";
0x3cfcad0: value = 61030776 = 0x3a364a0
-> mystruct[4] = "hello";
0x3cfcae0: value 61040928 = 0x3a36920 = ' '
-> printf("%s\n", mystruct[4]);
hello
value = 6 = 0x6
```

Things would get tricky as your struct got larger, and if there were padding.  E.g., `struct { char, int }` could have a size of 6 or 8 depending on your processor's alignment requirements, so you'd have to be aware of that when trying to get the offset of the `int`.  If it got too complicated, you could compile helper functions in your code that perhaps look like this pseudo code:

```
struct st { char a; int b; char *c; };
struct st *make_me_a_struct(char a, int b, char *c)
{
    struct st *newstruct = malloc(sizeof(st));
    newstruct->a = a;
    newstruct->b = b;
    newstruct->c = c;
    return newstruct;
}
```